# Is it possible to configure multiple database mail id in single account name in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, database-mail, event-notification

I would like to say that as i want to configure multiple database mail in single account name in sql server 2012.

This is SQL-Cluster-DB , so as per direction from head, If any sql job will fail , then notification should be myself (i,e; DBA) as well as System Administrator.

For single account name , a single email id is working properly.  when i am going to change 'Outgoing mail server (SMTP)' with one mail id to two mail id like this way:

```
Outgoing mail server (SMTP)
Email address : first mail id; second mail id
display name : MS SQL Server 2012 Backup notification
reply e-mail : first mail id; second mail id
Server name : (My company mail server)                    Port NO:(my company smtp mail port no)
```

After configuration of multiple mail id in email address , i am getting this error

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2015-12-02T10:36:37).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (**The specified**
>   **string is not in the form required for an e-mail address**.). )

when i am remove one email id from email address as well as reply e-mail of SMTP require configuration , then test mail is working properly.

My Question is like that:
1) Is it possible to configure multiple emailid alert notification in a single account
) Again required 'second account name' for second email alert notification.

My Working environment of SQL server 2012 is like that :

```
1) windows server 2012 R2
1) Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)
3)SQL Server is in Cluster Environment (that's why multiple sql alerts notification required)
4)System is in Domain environment.
5)It's Online Server
```

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to create an email account with single email id then Create  OPERATOR and add email ids to that operator as many as you want.

Comment: @AA.SC,As your instruction, i have created single an email account in SMTP, Also created Operator (like "SQL Job Failure")  . And "SQL Job Failure" Operator email name , i have given multiple email id. But still getting same error.

Comment: @AA.SC, Is there required any distribution list within mailing list.

Comment: did you verified your profile by sending test emails? If yes and its working fine then follow steps to create operator mentioned in answer.

Comment: @AA.SC, Yes i did verified with sending test email. For Single email it's working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Database Email operator

Step 1: 
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3:
[image]

One More step enable Sql Server Agent properties for notifying alerts and restart agent once these properties are settled.

Sql Server Agent  -> Properties ->
[image]

Comment: you are awesome. You saved my a day.