# SQL Server Alerts (notify operator when job failed)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent, alerts

I setup database mail, created an operator today and enable notify operator when job failed.

Is that all or do I need to create an alert too?

My boss just needs emails if any job failed.

Also how to test it to see it will work in the future?

Thanks

Comment: Alex,It's a duplicate question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122650/is-it-possible-to-configure-multiple-database-mail-id-in-single-account-name-in?s=3|0.7840

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the status of job run, that's the correct steps.

However, its recommended you configure the alerts for any database corruption, HW/SW failures or any other cause for an outage. Read [here](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configure-sql-server-alerts/) to configure the same.

In order to test, create a TEST job and purposefully make it fail and see if you receive the failure notification email or not.

Comment: ok,if there is production replication jobs running what to do in order to configure the alert system option in SQL server agent properties,shall we stop the replication 1st or wait till after working hours or do it and might not effect the replication jobs.